# Como obtener el token de firebase en el entorno de desarrollo de Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase-messaging

Tengo un problema a la hora de obtener el token para las notificaciones de FCM.

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.requestPermission().then(
        function(){
            console.log("permiso");
            return messaging.getToken();
        }
    ).then(function(token){
        console.log(token);
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log("error ocurred");
    });
```

Cuando llega a la parte de `messaging.getToken()`, me lanza este error en consola:
`The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto pasaba porque estaba buscando el script firebase-messaging-sw.js en otra ruta.